# Set default lang as English

Tags: php, get, default, lang

I'm using this script:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch ($lang){
    case "nl":
        //echo "PAGE FR";
        include("talen/nl.php");//include check session FR
        break;
    case "es":
        //echo "PAGE IT";
        include("talen/es.php");
        break;
    case "en":
        //echo "PAGE EN";
        include("talen/en.php");
        break;        
    default:
        //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
        include("talen/en.php");//include EN in all other cases of different lang detection
        break;
}
```

But when I set browser language to "af" it doesnt get the default english language...

How can I make that happen?

EDIT:

Because I have no case "af" it doesnt show anything...

When there is no case like "af" I want the default to be "en" but that doesnt work

Edit2:

I'm using this now:

```
<?
$accept_lang = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
$accept_lang = str_replace(' ', '', $accept_lang);

$arr = explode(',', $accept_lang);

$lang = "en";
$q = 0;

if (count($arr) > 0) {
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
    $l = explode(';', $a);

    if (count($l) == 1) {
        $l[1] = 'q=1';  
    }

    $l[1] = str_replace('q=', '', $l[1]);

    if ($l[1] > $q) {
        $q = $l[1];
    $lang = $l[0];  
    }
}
}

$lang = preg_replace('/-(.*)/', '', $lang);

switch ($lang){
    case "nl":
        //echo "PAGE FR";
        include("talen/nl.php");//include check session FR
        break;
    case "es":
        //echo "PAGE IT";
        include("talen/es.php");
        break;
    case "en":
        //echo "PAGE EN";
        include("talen/en.php");
        break;        
    default:
        //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
        include("talen/en.php");//include EN in all other cases of different lang detection
}
?>
```

But my $lang is still set to "af" and not the default "en"

EDIT 3:

Thanks for your help:

When I try use this:

```
print $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
switch ($lang){
    case "nl":
        //echo "PAGE FR";
        print("nl");//include check session FR
        break;
    case "es":
        //echo "PAGE IT";
        print("es");
        break;
    case "en":
        //echo "PAGE EN";
        print("en");
        break;        
    default:
        //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
        print("en");//include EN in all other cases of different lang detection
        break; 
}
```

It print out this:

af,nl;q=0.8,en;q=0.5,en-us;q=0.3en

But I still got "af".. how

Just for you to know... I got my browser language set to "af" to test it.. just that you know... But it should be load the default with your sript...

Comment: How are you setting the browser language to "af"? Have you confirmed that the value of the variable is what you expect? (Hint: The format of Accept-Langauge header is a lot more complicated than "An ISO language code")

Comment: I tried in my code by setting $lang = 'af' and its works fine. Just try to echo what u are getting in $lang variable.

Comment: What does `print $lang;` and `print $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];` (insert right before the `switch`) show!?

Comment: afaf-ZA,nl-NL;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.5,en-GB;q=0.3

Comment: @SJFrK can you help me out? I cant figure out why it aint working

Comment: I checked the code in your second edit with your accept language string and it works for me (I changed the switch to print the language instead of including a file). Try replacing your includes with simple `print` statements, especially `print 'default';` for the default case and see if it prints the expected (default) value.

Comment: Re third edit: First print statement: `af,nl;q=0.8,en;q=0.5,en-us;q=0.3`, second print statement: `en`. Also print some line breaks to understand the output better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like this script I wrote some time ago, which checks for the language with the best quantity value:

```
$accept_lang = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
$accept_lang = str_replace(' ', '', $accept_lang);

$arr = explode(',', $accept_lang);

$lang = 'en';
$q = 0;

if (count($arr) > 0) {
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
    $l = explode(';', $a);

    if (count($l) == 1) {
        $l[1] = 'q=1';  
    }

    $l[1] = str_replace('q=', '', $l[1]);

    if ($l[1] > $q) {
        $q = $l[1];
    $lang = $l[0];  
    }
}
}

$lang = preg_replace('/-(.*)/', '', $lang);
```

Then you can switch() over `$lang` like you did.

Omit the `break;` on the default: case, though.

**Edit**:

I changed `$lang = 'de';` to `$lang = 'en';`. This is the default language that is taken if `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` is empty.

Comment: Ok and how should I use this with my code I have for now? I'm not a great php'er so is there no solution for this with the code I have now with the language cases I'm working with?

Comment: Same as you did, but replace `$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);` with my code above.

Comment: I tried your code but cant get it to work... See edit in my post

Answer (score -2):

Just try to do one think. remove **break;** from default case.

Comment: Ok I did that and to give a answer to the other questions:

Comment: `break;` for `default` is not a problem.